# Render a link field inside a paragraph template drupal 8

Tags: twig, drupal-8, paragraph

I have a paragraph called link. In this paragraph there is a single link field that allows multiple values. In the paragraph-link.html.twig file I want to render all of the links added to the paragraph. Instead I get the same link duplicated as many times as the number of link values. So if I add two links, it renders the first link twice. I also need it to work with external and internal links. Currently it only renders the external links properly (but only ever renders the first one).

```
        {% for item in paragraph.field_link %}
            <a href="{{ paragraph.field_link.uri }}">{{ paragraph.field_link.title }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the comments, the following is working for external links but not internal ones. Internal link URI renders as "internal:/"

```
{% for item in paragraph.field_link %}
    <a href="{{ item.uri }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are calling the same variable `x` times. U need to call the correct property of `item`, not `paragraph`

Comment: Hard to tell without the data structure of `paragraph.field_link`. But you should start by using the current `item` build by the loop: `<a href="{{ item.uri }}">{{ item.title }}</a>`

Comment: Thanks DarkBee and β.εηοιτ.βε I now have it working with external links but internal links  don't render the uri. I updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

With the help of the comments I was able to get this working as I wanted within the paragraph template. Below is the working code for a Link field that allows multiple values within a paragraph field.

```
{% for item in paragraph.field_link %} 
    <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```